# What is the source for singing Od Yishama at a wedding?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, wedding

What is the (earliest) source for singing Od Yishama at the wedding?

The words are part of the last of the sheva brachos that are said by the wedding. But I'm curious about the switching from sheva brachos to singing the words.

Comment: Are you asking about a specific tune or the words in general? The words are part of the last of the sheva brachos that are said by the wedding.

Comment: The Or HaYashar (1760s) mentions a case of Sheva Brachos where the groom got up to speak, and, "as was the practice", his buddies interrupted him with singing. Doesn't say what they were singing. (Then again there were far more significant things going on in that case!) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_of_Cleves

Comment: @Chatzkel, I'm curious about that last part. The switching from sheva brachos to singing the words.

Comment: Related question -- who composed (and when) the tune most commonly sung? (Presumably the second one here: https://www.zemirotdatabase.org/view_song.php?id=60#rec )

Comment: @Shalom I heard my uncles say that one of the earlier Gerrer Rebbes composed it at a wedding. However, it's a famous question actually. I think there was a discussion and a different claim in one of the mainstream frum publications like mishpacha or something back a few years ago.